# jQuery keypress not working on simple bing search

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I head to bing.com and open the developer console and run

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// wait for it to load
jQuery.noConflict();

var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 72;
jQuery(".b_searchbox").trigger(press);
```

I would expect the letter h to appear in the search box.

If I use `val()` it works but why not the simulated keypress?